# What happened here (Sigma Sign)?

Tags: linear-algebra

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9HTB.png[image]

The red part is my main problem. I don't get why I can change just the upper border. Can somebody please explain? I tried so many ways and failed..

Comment: "why I can change just the upper border": They didn't change **just** the upper border; they also changed the terms being added.  In addition to reading amcalde's answer, you might just write out what those sums over $k$ are for some nice small value of $n$, say $n=1$, where the first sum over $k$ has just two terms and the second has four.  That way you can see exactly what's going on without a lot of notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write$$f(a) = \frac{x^ay^{2n+1-a}}{a!(2n+1-a)!}$$
Look at the summand:
$$\frac{x^{2k+1}y^{2n+1-(2k+1)}}{(2k+1)!(2n+1-(2k+1))!} + \frac{x^{2k}y^{2n+1-2k}}{(2k)!(2n+1-2k)!} = f(2k+1) + f(2k)$$
The two pieces here are almost the same except one has $(2k+1)$ everywhere the other has $(2k)$.
So you have $$\sum_{k=0}^n f(2k+1) + f(2k) = f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(2n) + f(2n+1)$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} f(k)$$

Comment: Too right. Thanks for the catch @ColmBhandal